# How to filter rows with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set as I've shown below.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~shop_id,  ~id,      ~key,        ~date,      ~status, 
  "1",       "10",     "abc",    '2020-05-04',   'good',
  "1",       "10",     "def",    '2020-05-03',   'normal',
  "1",       "10",     "glm",    '2020-05-03',   'bad',
  "1",       "20",     "ksr",    '2020-05-01',   'bad',
  "1",       "20",     "tyz",    '2020-05-02',   'bad',
  "2",       "20",     "uyv",    '2020-05-01',   'good',
  "2",       "20",     "mys",    '2020-05-01',   'normal',
  "2",       "30",     "ert",    '2020-05-01',   'bad',
  "2",       "40",     "yer",    '2020-05-05',   'good',
  "2",       "40",     "tet",    '2020-05-05',   'bad',
)
```

Now, I want to filter the data with the following conditions:

Group the data by `shop_id` and `id`, then look at the date. Then,

1. If the `date` is minimum when `status == 'bad'`, then remove the rows. For instance, the first three rows were removed from the data set because of this condition. (please see desired_df)
2. If there is only the status of `'bad'`, leave all the rows. Because of this condition, 4th and 5th rows left in the desired data set.
3. If the `date` is the same among the rows when `status == 'bad'`, then leave both rows in the desired data set.

In other words, I only want to see the rows when the date of 'bad' status is the maximum after we grouped the shop_id and id. But when the date of the status is the same in both statuses, keep the rows.

```
desired_df <- tribble(
  ~shop_id,  ~id,      ~key,      ~date,      ~status, 
  "1",       "20",     "ksr",   '2020-05-01',   'bad',
  "1",       "20",     "tyz",   '2020-05-02',   'bad',
  "2",       "30",     "ert",   '2020-05-01',   'bad',
  "2",       "40",     "yer",   '2020-05-05',   'good',
  "2",       "40",     "tet",   '2020-05-05',   'bad', 
)
```

Any help or assistance would be really appreciated!

Comment: from your explanation I don't understand why the first row is removed. It's status is not `bad` and the date is not minimum. Please can you clarify?

Comment: Because when shop_id == '1' and id == '10', the minimum date belongs to the 'bad' status. That's why we removed the first three rows. Is it clear now or? @AmitKohli

Comment: How is 1 the same as 10?

Comment: Sorry, I've just corrected my sentence @Edward

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `case_when`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(shop_id,id) %>% 
  mutate(filter = case_when(all(status != "bad") ~ FALSE,
                            all(status == "bad") ~ TRUE,
                            all(status[date == min(date)] == "bad") ~ FALSE,
                            any(status[date == min(date)] == "good") ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  filter(filter == TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-filter)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   shop_id, id [3]
  shop_id id    key   date       status
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr> 
1 1       20    ksr   2020-05-01 bad   
2 1       20    tyz   2020-05-02 bad   
3 2       30    ert   2020-05-01 bad   
4 2       40    yer   2020-05-05 good  
5 2       40    tet   2020-05-05 bad
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! For the last criteria, when shop_id == '2' & id == '40', there is only one date where is '2020-05-05' for both status of 'good' and 'bad'. That's why I wanted to keep both rows since I can not compare the dates. @Ian Campbell

Comment: Line shop_id == '2' & id == '40' should be removed by the rule "if the date is minimum when status == 'bad', then remove the rows."

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad English. To avoid this misunderstanding, I've added the third condition. Because in the line shop_id == '2' & id == '40', we have the same date for the status of 'good', too. I wish I could have the 'hour' in date, but I don't have it. That's why I keep both.

Comment: Why is line shop_id == '2' & id == '20' removed? There is no rule specifically removing it.

Comment: Because there is no 'bad' status for this line, so there is again no comparison point on 'bad' status. Imagine that bad means deleted status. I basically want to see the lines that never come back to the data. If there is no 'bad' status, that means it is already never deleted.

Comment: I still do not understand why group shop_id == 1 & id ==10 is removed when status == "bad" on date == min(date), but group shop_id == 2 & id ==40 is not removed when status == "bad" on date == min(date).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213201/discussion-between-zineda-and-ian-campbell).